# Is the STEREO-A and STEREO-B imagery publicly available?

Tags: the-sun, space-probe

The latest image on the [NASA STEREO image page] is from December, and I assume STEREO-A and -B have collected data since. Can this data be found online?

Comment: Communication with STEREO-B (Behind) was lost on October 1 2014, re-established for approx a month in August 2016 and then lost again. Attempts to recover the spacecraft were halted in October 2018; more info available in the [status update](https://stereo-ssc.nascom.nasa.gov/behind_status.shtml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Imagery](https://stereo-ssc.nascom.nasa.gov/pub/browse/2022/02/17/) is available from the [STEREO Science Center](https://stereo-ssc.nascom.nasa.gov/pub/) along with other data like [telemetry](https://stereo-ssc.nascom.nasa.gov/pub/telemetry/).  The image below is an example of the image browsing and selection interface.  There may be a more direct way to browse the catalog as well.

[image]